# Creating vector with intervals drawn from Poisson process

Tags: python, random, statistics, poisson

I'm looking for some advice on how to implement some statistical models in Python. I'm interested in constructing a sequence of z values (z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_n) where the number of jumps in an interval (z_1,z_2] is distributed according to the Poisson distribution with parameter lambda(z_2-z_1)
[image]

and the numbers of random jumps over disjoint intervals are independent random variables. I want my piecewise constant plot to look something like the two images below, where the y axis is Y(z), where Y(z) consists of N(0,1) random variables in each interval say.

To construct the z data, what would be the best way to tackle this? I have tried sampling values via `np.random.poisson` and then taking a cumulative sum, but the values drawn are repeated for small intensity values. Please any help or thoughts would be really helpful. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your code?  And what is your lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.random.poisson` is used to sample the count of events that occured in `[z_i, z_j)`.  if you want to sample the events as they occur, then you just want the exponential distribution.  for example:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 50
z = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(1/n, size=n))
y = np.random.normal(size=n)
```

plotting these (using [`step` in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)) gives something similar to your plots:

[image: plotting z vs y]

note the `1/n` sets a "lambda" so on average we expect `n` points within `[0,1]`.  in this case we got slightly less so it overshoot.  feel free to rescale if that's important to you

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the 1/n is equal to the intensity lambda in the Poisson process? I was expecting the average difference between elements in the z vector to be n, but it is actually 1/n...

Comment: people/libraries parameterise things differently; numpy and scipy tend to be annoyingly different than stats conventions.  it's a "scale" factor here, rather than a "rate", hence the reciprocal.  i'd suggest looking up docs and/or doing simulations to make sure things are how you'd expect them